# Does this very interesting property hold for all maximal prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I've been trying to understand a little bit better a property that I've noticed on the current list of maximal prime gaps on Wikipedia. It's as follows:
$\\$

**Problem**

Let $g_n$ and $g_{n+k}$ be the $n$-th and $(n+k)$-th prime gaps respectively - both of them also being maximal prime gaps. Does the inequality

$g_{n+k} - g_n ≤ k$

hold for any two maximal prime gaps?

$\\$

EDIT:

I removed the restriction that I had earlier that there couldn't be any other maximal prime gaps between $g_n$ and $g_{n+k}$. This is so that the inequality applies to any chosen pair of maximal prime gaps.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you written simple code to explore?

Comment: I haven't written any code but I can give some examples. Take the maximal prime gap $g4=4$ and $g2=2$ and $g4−g2≤2$. The same result holds for the entire list of maximal prime gaps on Wikipedia.

Comment: I see no reason why two records could not occur in a sequence of $3$ consecutive primes $p<q<r$ ($q-p$ a record gap and $r-q$ still larger). This would refute this inequality. Determining more maximum prime gaps will be very time-consuming, so I see little hope to prove or disprove this conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's a shame there's not much hope of a proof (or counterexample). But at least now I have a more realistic view of the difficulty of this problem.